# auth/app-not-authorized This app is not authorized to use Firebase Authentication. Please verify that the correct package name and SHA-1

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

Please help! Ive been trying so much methods but yet still I get the error:

```
[auth/app-not-authorized] This app is not authorized to use Firebase Authentication. Please verify that the correct package name and SHA-1 are configured in the Firebase Console
```

Im trying to sign in with phone auth on a react native app with firebase.
Im using https://rnfirebase.io/auth/phone-auth

Ive enabled Phone number sign in on firebase. Ive enabled Android Device Check API. Ive created an android project on firebase with the package name being the same name as the package name in my code base. Ive added the fingerprints to firebase, both SHA-1 and SHA-265. These fingerprints are the fingerprints under google play console -> app integrity -> app signing. Ive also added the fingerprints that logs out when I enter this command: ./gradlew signingreport. Ive always updated the google-services.json file when I changed things. Ive cleaned the android folder and rebuilt it but still I keep getting that error. I am using a real device.

Comment: Try to generate new SHA-1/SHA-265, add it to firebase project and download new google-services.json.
But have you tried to use firebase signInWithEmailAndPassword? It works at your project?

Comment: signInWithEmailAndPassword work perfectly fine, we decided to move onto phone number sign in.